# I am able to login using server, client and x509 authentication in MongoDB community edition

Tags: database-design, mongodb, authentication, ssl

I am trying to configure x509 authentication for mongodb community edition. Though I have configured the same, I am able to login using server as well as client authentication along with x509 auth. Is this the normal behavior of the setup or am I making any mistakes.

Please help me on this. Thanks in advance

Comment: You have provided zero details of how exactly you have configured authentication or how you connect, so your question is impossible to answer.

Comment: You can enable clients by username/password or x509 certificate, and yes you can have both at the same time but not for the same user, of course. As you don't provide any MongoDB server configuration settings, nor any certificate properties nor the way how you connect, nobody here can answer your question. What do you mean by "I am able to login using server authentication"?

Comment: Entries from my config file:
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1
  tls:
      mode: requireTLS
      certificateKeyFile: D:\certnew\MongoDb\Test3\test-server.pem
      CAFile: D:\certnew\MongoDb\Test3\test-ca.pem

security:
  authorization: enabled
  clusterAuthMode: x509

Comment: Connect with server Certificate:
mongosh --tls --tlsCertificateKeyFile D:\certnew\MongoDb\Test3\test-server.pem --tlsCAFile D:\certnew\MongoDb\Test3\test-ca.pem
Connect with Client Certificate:
mongosh --tls --tlsCertificateKeyFile D:\certnew\MongoDb\Test3\test-client.pem --tlsCAFile D:\certnew\MongoDb\Test3\test-ca.pem
Trying to connect with x509 Auth:
mongosh --tls --tlsCertificateKeyFile D:\certnew\MongoDb\Test3\test-client.pem --tlsCAFile D:\certnew\MongoDb\Test3\test-ca.pem --authenticationDatabase '$external' --authenticationMechanism MONGODB-X509
I want only x509 authentication

Comment: Please edit your question and add information there instead of putting it into a comment. It's very hard to read.